# Scope elements are not binding

Tags: angularjs

In my application ng-model data is not binding to controller,ng-model name is same as scope name but not getting why it is not binding.getting as undefined.

```
$scope.updateData = function() {
    debugger;
    $scope.userId = sessionStorage.getItem("User Id");
    var data = {
        'eMPLOYEEID' :$scope.userId,
        'firstName' :$scope.fName
    };
    console.log(data);
```

}

Html code

```
<form >
          <div>
          <input type="text" ng-model="fName"/>
          <button type="submit" class="submitbtn"  ng-click="updateData()">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: you haven't shown enough of the HTML code here, particularly where the `ng-controller` is defined;  also, this doesn't happen to be inside an `ng-repeat`?

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you binded your controllers correctly
Try either of these ways

```
<form >
          <div>
          <input type="text" ng-model="fName"/>
          <button class="submitbtn"  ng-click="updateData()">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

OR

```
<form onsubmit="updateData()">
          <div>
          <input type="text" ng-model="fName"/>
          <button type="submit" class="submitbtn"  >Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem, why it should not work. I didn't changed anything in HTML but wrote a controller using without sessionStorage. See the working solution.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.User_Id = 111;

    $scope.updateData = function() {
      var data = {
        'eMPLOYEEID': $scope.User_Id,
        'firstName': $scope.fName
      };
      console.log(data);
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="fName" />
      <button type="submit" class="submitbtn" ng-click="updateData()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```